# Ajax popup to "GET" action

Tags: c#, ajax, get, popup, action

I have a form in ajax popup.  I created a GET action to open popup and POST action to manage the form. The thing is that my "popup button" always goes to action POST. 
My "popup button" looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ajax-popup {url: '@Url.Action("NewsCategoryAdd")'}"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Open Form</button>
```

What can i do to force it to invoke GET action?

Comment: So you have 2 methods with the same name but one with an [HttpGet] attribute and one with an [HttpPost] attribute? Can you rename them to differentiate the actions?

Comment: @Cal279 This looks more like workaround but it works. Thanks.

Comment: OK, will put it as the answer in the absence of anything better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two controller methods with the same name but different request types (get/post), you can rename the HttpGet method to distinguish it from its HttpPost counterpart. This is more of a workaround than a solution but does at least remove any ambiguity when coding out the views.